# How to implement navigation between <span> with the arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am making my own combobox for better design than a `<select>` tag.

By the way, I wish to know, how to make possible the navigation with the arrow keys  of a keyboard between `<span>` (or other `<p>`...), and display the proposals with the "tab" key. Like the `<option>` of a `<select>` tag.

This is where I would like to make it work :

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" value=""/>
<div id="myDiv">
    <span>Value 1</span>    
    <span>Value 2</span>
    <span>Value 3</span>
</div>
```

​
CSS

```
#myDiv {display:none;border:1px solid #000;}
span  {display:block;background:#EDEDED;cursor:pointer;}
span:hover {background:#555;color:#FFF;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myInput').focus(function(){
        $('#myDiv').slideDown();
    });    

    $('span').click(function(){
         $('#myInput').val($(this).html());
         $('#myDiv').slideUp();
    });
});​
```

You can test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/eHpKX/2/

*Edit example : for example, click or tab in the input and then use the arrow keys to navigate... It doesn't works.*

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are lot of custom select jQuery plugins out there.. Which will have all the default select features implemented. One such light weight.. http://india.assigninfo.com/assignlabs/samples/jALDropDown1_7_5/App_Web/jALDropDown1_7_5.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want any plugin. I wish to do it by myself :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a keydown handler for `uparrow` and `downarrow` to act like select drop down. However `tab` key has a specific role in tabbing out to next field, So I didn't want to `prevtDefault` browser behavior. See below code and you can build it more from there,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHpKX/7/)

**CSS:**

```
span.active {background:#555;color:#FFF;}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myInput').focus(function() {
        if ($('#myDiv span.active').length == 0) {
            $('#myDiv span:first').addClass('active');
        }
        $('#myDiv').slideDown();
    }).focusout(function() {
        $('#myDiv').slideUp();
    });
    $('span').click(function() {
        $('#myInput').val($(this).html());
    }).mouseenter(function() {
        $('#myDiv span').removeClass('active');
    }).keydown(function(e) {
        alert(e.which);

    });

    //keydown event
    $('#myInput').keydown(function(e) {
        var $actvOpt = $('#myDiv span.active');
        if (e.which == 13) { //enter key
            if ($actvOpt.length != 0) {
                $(this).val($actvOpt.text());
                $('#myDiv').slideUp();
            }
            return;
        }

        var actvIndex = $actvOpt.removeClass('active').index();
        var optCount = $('#myDiv span').length;

        if (e.which == 40) { //keydown
            actvIndex += 1;
        } else if (e.which == 38) { //keydown
            actvIndex -= 1;
        }

        if (actvIndex < 0) actvIndex = optCount - 1;
        else if (actvIndex >= optCount) actvIndex = 0;

        $('#myDiv span:eq(' + actvIndex + ')').addClass('active');

        $actvOpt = $('#myDiv span.active');
        $(this).val($actvOpt.text());        
    });
});
```

Comment: Terrific ! But the span doesn't get any focus, so I don't think to be able to update the input with an enter keypress. For the tabulation, I've found a solution with inputs..., I've implemented it in your solution, but tab and arrows don't do the same, please have a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/eHpKX/6/

Comment: @Valky Having an input field as an option is not a suggested method. We can do something for enter key. Let me see. Btw, How do you want `tab` to behave. In regular select box, tabs doesn't do jump to next options.. it jumps to next input field.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm a bit nut ! Tab will only have to display the div like the click on the main input, and arrows to select a field. Then click or enter key striked send the value to the main input.

Comment: @Valky See updated code for Enter key press and also keydown/keyup will update the textbox value dynamically.

Comment: It's perfect, I will be able to change some features on it now. Thanks a lot. I've also changed the title of my topic...